# If two Turing machines halt iff they find a proof that the other halts, does either of them necessarily halt?

Tags: logic, turing-machines

*This question was inspired by [this excellent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427842/will-this-turing-machine-find-a-proof-of-its-halting/) on MathOverflow.*

Assume that there are two Turing machines $M$ and $N$ that search through all ZFC proofs in some order, and if either of them finds a proof that the other halts, then it would halt. If the machines are identical in design, then, by the answers on the MathOverflow question, they would halt. However, if the machines are different, can they continue running forever or would one of them halt at some point? If one halts, then the other would halt because it was proven to halt.

Comment: I think yes, arguing as follows: arguing as in the other thread, we have that if "$M_1$ halts or $M_2$ halts" is (provably) provable (which, as I understand, is your hypothesis), then (provably) $M_1$ halts or $M_2$ halts. Then, as you say, it follows that they both in fact halt. It'd rather not post this as an answer, though, since I may not have enough background to miss some nuances here.

Comment: Both might run forever, however...

Comment: If provably one of them halts, then no, they can't.

Comment: How did you interpret my question?

Comment: That you have two Turing machines with the property that each of them halts if the other provably halts, and you ask whether they do, in fact, halt.

Comment: This is what I meant in my question.

Comment: Clarify ‘same order.’

Comment: @Aruralreader   I wrote 'some order.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**$\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably, both machines will halt.** The argument is pretty much identical to the MO question you linked to: it's a consequence of Lob's theorem and $\Sigma_1$-completeness of the theory involved.

Let's focus on $M$ WLOG (the proof for $N$ is identical).

The following reasoning takes place in $\mathsf{ZFC}$: suppose $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that $M$ halts. Then $N$ will find such a proof, and so $N$ will halt. Since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is $\Sigma_1$-complete, this means that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can prove "$N$ halts" and so $M$ will eventually halt.

This means that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "If $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that $M$ halts, then $M$ halts." But applying [Lob's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem), this gives us a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of "$M$ halts."

Comment: What is sigma-1 completeness?

Comment: @mathlander A theory is $\Sigma_1$-complete if it proves every true $\Sigma_1$ fact about the natural numbers. Equivalently, it proves all true (but not necessarily *only* true) halting facts about specific Turing machines on specific inputs. $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provably $\Sigma_1$-complete; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258431/who-first-proved-that-we-can-prove-that-we-prove-things-we-prove).